# display an image in Perl script

Tags: apache, perl

I have a small code and trying to run into web.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new();

print   $cgi->header,
        $cgi->start_html('Login Page');


print   $cgi->img( { -src => "karvy.jpeg" ,align=>'LEFT' } );

print $cgi->end_html;
```

Whenever i'm browsing this program into web.The image is not showing there and getting below an error

[image]

Httpd Log

```
root]# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log

[Sat Oct 18 07:54:46 2014] [error] Unrecognized character \\xFF in column 154 at /var/www/perl/karvy.jpeg line 1.\n
```

Answer (score 2):

karvy.jpeg is in the cgi directory so it is being interpreted as a cgi script and not as a jpeg.  When the web page generated by login3.pl loads into the browser it tries to get karvy.jpeg from the same directory and as it is a jpeg image and not a script of any sort, the web server is confused

Comment: Seems reasonable, but when I try to load an image from a directory with `Options +ExecCGI` and `SetHandler cgi-script`, I get a completely different error: `(13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/html/image_test/foo.jpg' failed`. Adding execute permissions to the image gives `(8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/html/image_test/foo.jpg' failed`. This is on Apache v2.2.15, so perhaps the error is different for different versions?

Comment: If you are using apache you need to set the permissions in the apache configuration for the directory that the image is in, probably with a <Directory> section.  Most apache configs already have something like this already setup

Comment: That's exactly what I did (used a `<Directory>` section). You can of course do the same thing with `ScriptAlias /image_test/ "/var/www/html/image_test/"`, but the error message is the same. Have you reproduced the OP's error? (Not saying you're wrong, just curious if you were able to, since I can't. Wondering if a difference in the image file itself could cause the different error, or something like that.)

Comment: Aha, it looks like this may be [caused by mod_perl](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mod-perl/22661).

Comment: And I've reproduced the exact error message, so it was mod_perl after all. It would be helpful to add that info to your answer.

Comment: thnx a lot @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i got the solution by the given link.It is related to perl_mod.